# Electric potential in the far region?

Tags: taylor-expansion, electromagnetism

I have the electric potential

$$\Phi(\vec{x})=\frac{\lambda}{2\varepsilon_0}\log\left(\frac{R+\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}{|z|}\right),$$
whose behavior I have to study in the far and near region, i.e. expand them in $z\gg R$ or $z\ll R$, respectively. The solutions provided read
$$\Phi(\vec{x})=\frac{\lambda}{2\varepsilon_0}\left(\log\left(\frac{|z|}{|z|}\right)+\frac{R}{|z|}+...\right)$$
for the far region and
$$\Phi(\vec{x})=\frac{\lambda}{2\varepsilon_0}\left(\log\left(\frac{2R}{|z|}\right)+...\right)$$
in the near region.

However, when I perform a Taylor expansion in these two points I do not get these results. Can anyone explain how to arrive at them?

Answer (score 0):

For $|z| \ll R$ (near field), we have $$\begin{split}
\frac{R+\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}{|z|} &= \frac{R+R\sqrt{1+\frac {z^2
}{R^2}}}{|z|}\\
&= \frac {R +R +\cdots}{|z|}\\
&= \frac {2R}{|z|}+\cdots
\end{split}$$
This yields the answer for the near field.

For $|z| \gg R$ (far field), we have $$\begin{split}
\frac{R+\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}{|z|} &= \frac{R+z\sqrt{\frac {R^2
}{z^2} +1}}{|z|}\\
&= \frac {R +z(1 + \frac {R^2}{2z^2} +\cdots)}{|z|}\\
&= \frac z {|z|} + \frac {R}{|z|} +\cdots
\end{split}$$
This gives you the answer for the far field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this does not yield the potential given in my solutions. Note that for the far field only the first summand contains a $\log$, the second does not.